# Tweepy not returning full list of users

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy

Hi so I am very new to python and I am trying to write this code to utilize tweepy to pull all the users that have used a particular hashtag. The hashtag is very low volume roughly 30 tweets as of now but when I run the script it is only returning 12 names. Just curious if it is something I am doing wrong that is preventing me from pulling the full list of names.

```
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

search_words = "#Testhashtag"
date_since = "2019-06-12"

new_search = search_words

tweets = tw.Cursor(
    api.search,
    q=new_search,
    lang="en",
    since=date_since).items(9999999999)

users_locs = [[tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.created_at] for tweet in 
tweets]

tweet_text = pd.DataFrame(
    data=users_locs,
    columns=['Username', "Date Posted"])

tweet_text.drop_duplicates(
    subset="Username",
    keep='first', inplace=True)
```

Was also wondering how to incorporate a count of all the tweets using that hashtag to check to see if that is the total number of users outputted.

Comment: Have you checked the API docs to see if there are limitations in what's returned?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the below link `api.search` has a parameter named `count` which will limit your results.

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py

you may be able to get more result by set the count more than the default one.So you code would be like this:

```
tweets = tw.Cursor(
    api.search,
    q=new_search,
    lang="en",
    count=50,
    since=date_since).items(9999999999)
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it and unfortunately I did not get anymore results. From my understanding that acts the same as .items which I set to 9999999999 to get max results

Comment: hmm. You're right. So maybe other arguments would need to change. Try to read the documentation of tweepy which defines `max_id`  which is another way to solve the problem.